# Goodsync (gsync) linux always overwriting files to S3 (cant identify similarity)

Tags: backup, timestamps, amazon-s3

I have been using Linux `gsync`, as described below, by creating the jobs in OSX (local dir to S3) and then exporting the tix file out. That more-or-less seemed to work.

HOWEVER---
The `gsync` on Linux log is showing a message that it can't mark timestamps on the S3 side. As a result, every backup that runs is overwriting every file again with the message *"An older version is overwriting a newer version"*

QUESTION---
Ie there a linux switch command to tell `gsync` to ignore the timestamp and only use file sizes. Or simply ignore overwriting the file if the file exists. Or another solution :D

I.e.

```
gsync job-update /?=ignore-time
```

or something.

Answer (score 0):

From Goodsync support(after two weeks):

```
William replied (2017/06/14 08:41 am EDT)   
there is no such option.

you should use only GS to sync to S3, then it stores good file mod time in state file and it can handle time translation.
```

So, basically, `gsync` on linux doesn't 'really' support S3. While it WILL copy the files out to S3, it can't recognize if a file to be copied is the same as the file that already exists in the S3.

So, if you set a directory to sync to S3, it will copy the entire directory to S3 - every time.

Maybe they'll do something about that someday :)